# GMap.Net: Process takes a long time to close after window closes

Tags: c#, wpf, lag, gmap.net

I am testing out GMap.Net using WPF. So far I have only added the GMapControl, as well as setting some necessary stuff (CacheLocation, MapProvider, Zoom etc). The control is working well, except that when I close my window, it takes a while before VS recognizes that the debugging session has closed.

Apparently, my application's process is still running for some time before it terminates - it's not a bug in VS. This delay only appears when I do zoom/pan just before I close the window. I would want to guess something is still running, but I'm not sure how to tackle this problem.

Has anyone encountered this and have a solution?

Comment: Did you try to ask this on their [Discussions](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions) page?

Comment: Not an answer, but since you asked for it: no I've not experienced any lag behavior having used the lib in both winforms and wpf.

Comment: @Clemens I managed to trace where the delay comes from, it comes from `GMaps`'s `CacheEngine` thread. Apparently it is still trying to do the whole queue of caching operations. It is not disposable and the nearest thing to clear it is `CancelTileCaching()`, which is not called by GMapControl's `Dispose()` method.

Comment: @rdoubleui The lag not during the usage, it's between closing the mainwindow and having the application fully terminated.

Answer (score 3):

What is happening is your program is still caching the tiles.

All you have to do is call `gMap.Manager.CancelTileCaching();` when you exit your program or close the form.

`gMap` is what I named my instance of `gMap.Net`

Comment: Yup, that is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a there is a thread still running. I have noticed that the classes use the IDisposable interface. When you close the application/window, it is recommended that you call the .Dispose() method to clear any resources in use

Comment: I have subclassed GMapControl and overridden `Dispose()`, it is already called right when I close the main window. But it still takes about 3 to 4 seconds after that before the process terminates.